# Parsing JSON - TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-2.7, sorting

I need to retrieve GoDaddy certificates name and expiration dates. I`m trying code like this:

```
def get_cert():
    customerId = "UUID"
    cert_url = "https://api.godaddy.com//v2/customers/%s/certificates" %(customerId)

    cert_response = requests.get(cert_url, headers=headers)
    cert_dict = json.loads(cert_response.text)
    for cert in cert_dict:
        cert_name = (cert['commonName'])
        print(cert_name)
```

and getting error like:

```
    cert_name = (cert['commonName'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Output from the API call without parsing:

```
        {
            "certificateId": "ID", 
            "commonName": "*.domain.co.uk", 
            "completedAt": "2021-01-12T14:26:36Z", 
            "createdAt": "2020-04-02T14:25:06Z", 
            "period": 1, 
            "serialNumber": "NUMBER", 
            "status": "CURRENT", 
            "type": "DV_WILDCARD_SSL", 
            "validEndAt": "2022-05-04T14:26:32Z", 
            "validStartAt": "2021-04-02T14:26:32Z"
        }
```

I have the same code for GoDaddy domains API and it works properly (logic is the same, difference only in API URL and keys) so I can`t understand why its forbidden to cut json output by "commonName"  and "validEndAt" in this case.

Comment: In cases like this it's really useful to use a debugger; in this instance you'd want to step through the loop that's failing and see what the value of `cert` is at the point of failure. A debugger is basically a day 1, programming 101 thing to learn, so if you don't know how to use one yet this is a great opportunity to get acquainted with one. I suggest the PyCharm debugger.

Comment: Your line: `for cert in cert_dict:` implies that each `cert` is a string since a json object must have string keys.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that what you are receiving is the data type you are assuming it is. The code you have is suitable if the decoding yields a `list` instance containing `dict` objects. The error message you are receiving seems like you are getting a single `dict`.

When you iterate through a `dict`, you will receive all its keys. If you know exactly what key you want, you don't need to iterate over it.

```
def get_cert():
    customerId = "UUID"
    cert_url = "https://api.godaddy.com//v2/customers/%s/certificates" %(customerId)

    cert_response = requests.get(cert_url, headers=headers)
    cert_dict = json.loads(cert_response.text)
    print(cert_dict['commonName'])
```

This will throw an error if the key does not exist. Another way to try to retrieve it without any exceptions would be:

`common_name = cert_dict.get('commonName')`

If the key is not there, `common_name` would be `None`

Comment: Oh, thats really a thing, there is no such key as "commonName". Going to explore this API deeper..
Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear in my explanation, you were going through all the keys from the dictionary (meaning a list of string instances), and you were trying to get `['commonName']` of `"certificateId"`, which would get you to that error.